# Reading multiple data from single line

Tags: c, gcc, scanf

I'm currently working on a virtual machine and I'm trying to scan in instructions to my compiler from a file with multiple lines.
Each line is in the format: xx yyyy zzz
- xx : are ints (Representing memory location)
- yyyy : are chars or a string (Representing instruction)
- zzz : are also ints (Representing value to be stored)

Here's what I've tried:

```
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fPtr) != NULL)
{
    scanf(buf,"%d %s %d",&address,&string,&value);
        if(string == "SET")
        {
            printf("SET found");
        }
}
```

I've tried scanf, fscanf and a few others I can't remember.
Any help I can get is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It's not too late to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `if (sscanf(buf,"%d%5s%d",&address,string,&value) >= 2) { if (strcmp(string, "SET") == 0) { printf("SET found");  ...`  For a more complete answer, post a more complete question - something small that completely compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You unable to use the scanf in to get the input from the string. You have to use the sscanf function to get the input from the string.

Then your are passing a character array for the %s in scanf. That is incorrect. Because, "string" is the address for the character array string[0] not "&string".

So, you will try the below code.

```
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fPtr) != NULL)
{
    sscanf(buf,"%d%s%d",&address,string,&value);
        if(string == "SET")
        {
            printf("SET found");
        }
}
```